Issue with php move_uploaded_file, probably the file name
Not picking the problem here, this is at the end of a 14 hour coding binge so probably obvious
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => horror-scene-domestic-space.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )
newFile = ../news/1.jpg
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newFile);
File is not uploading, have an if statement around the php function which tells me it ain't working, but not why it ain't working. Sorry if late reply to question, but in need of sleep.

Okay added a couple of further error checks and we get  1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini', - d'uh some manual reading helped here. RTFM in play.

So please amend your php.ini to increase the upload_max_filesize (after amending the php.ini, please restart the httpd)

I dont now what kind a sever you are running but the guys above have the right answer you must edit your php.ini file and search file_uploads and set it to "on" and max_file_uploads increase the size to 5. save the file restart server.
Done.

Unfortunately most commercial server companies are not going to change ini settings for individual site preferences. Changing ini settings is pretty much a superficial answer. Sure fine for your own test servers, trying going to a live commercial server and asking the Admins to change any of the ini files.
We are going to investigate php's ability to read the ini variables and set those at limits with obvious error warnings prior to processing.
Thanks for the answer though.
Issue has been identified, we are now working around the problem as the software once completed is going to be in the public domain.
